# Conflicting idea about Karma in Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

In Bhagavad Gita Lord Krishna says that he is the reason why anything happens or why someone does something.

Also, the mighty God says that, a person will get results according to his karmas(deeds). Negative results for negative karmas and positive results for positive karmas.

Now, if everything happens because of God will, then a person killing other for no reason is also God's will.

So if all the things are occurring because of gods will, then why do we humans have to suffer the consequences?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84410/discussion-on-question-by-mayank-joshi-conflicting-idea-about-karma-in-bhagavad).

Comment: you should say which verses in the Gita that you don't understand. As it is your question is unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no conflict in Bhagavad Gita.

Bhagavan NEVER says he is the reason WHY someone does something.

[Brahma sutra 1.34](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc63662.html) clearly mention this :

> वैषम्यनैर्घृण्ये न सापेक्षत्वात् तथा हि दर्शयति |
>
> vaiṣamyanairghṛṇye na sāpekṣatvāt tathā hi darśayati |

The soil of earth is common to all. Without soil, no plant can grow. But depending on what seed the farmer sows, he reaps rice or wheat.

Similarly, God is common to all. Without God, no karma will have consequences. But depending on what karma you do, punya or papa, you reap happiness or sadness, respectively.

That is why we say God is the reason for anything HAPPENING, but he is not the reason for WHY a particular thing happened.

Just like your office for example, they are the reason for anything happening to you. Just because you go to work, if the company doesn't process payroll, you won't get salary. There is a school of philosophy which says 'Company is not necessary. Just do work, you'll get salary automatically'. That is silly.

So, you need the company. If they don't have infrastructure setup, you can't even do ANY work (whether good work or bad work). Without company, nothing happens. If you do good work, you get bonus. If you do bad work, you get citation. But what you do in the company determines your reward or punishment. Company is not responsible for you working overtime. They are also not responsible for you coming in late. But they are responsible for enforcing the consequences.

Similarly, without God creating infrastructure of universe, nobody can do anything. But he does not interfere whether you do good or bad within it.

It also doesn't mean God or Office don't care about you at all. They help you during new-hire orientation, they help you with senior team members, with mentors, manager, coaching etc. God helps you with vedas, shastras, itihasa, purana, does avataras himself to set example, gives us acharyas, parents.

But he leaves the final independence of deciding how to act, up to you. That is why all jivatama have svatantra, up to an extent.

Think about this - Do you ever ask :

> if all the things are occurring because of gods will, then why do we
>   humans have to ENJOY the consequences?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between being the cause of something and willing something. 
Sri Krishna is alluding to himself as being the cause (in the sense of the [immovable mover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmoved_mover) of Aristotle).
Here the "will" of "God" is not the key, it is to say that "God" is the cause of all things. 
In fact the very point of an *avatar* is to demonstrate to human beings that even that which we perceive as divinity is also subject to the laws of cause and effect to the extent that the divinity expresses itself as a limited sense of self that identifies with the action. Sri Krishna experiences the effects of both blessings and curses during the course of the Mahabharata in addition to the other human effects such as ageing and death.