# What do scriptures say about luck?

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for scriptural references which mention for and against *luck*.

Eg:

- Against luck, would be anything (but not limiting to) like *hard work creates luck*
- For luck, would be anything (but not limiting to) like *increasing luck by rituals and so on*.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: the Sanskrit word for luck is 'adrushta' (a+drushta = not+seen) i.e. results of actions performed so long ago that one cannot remember them. this includes actions of past births. in other words, there is no magical thing called luck. there are only consequences of actions that you performed. If you know your action e.g. you throw a stone up, and it falls on your head, it is called result. If you don't remember your action e.g. you threw a stone on someone's head in some previous birth, now suddenly one stone falls on you because some random person threw a stone, that is called 'luck'

Comment: @Ram Thanks and Sorry, for late very late reply. I didn't notice the comment at all. Question: Destiny is not pre-determined then? Like some say "everything is predetermined"

Comment: This is a very nuanced question. So read following with care : Destiny, by definition, means predetermined. Naturally, the next question is : which parts of my life are predetermined, and more importantly, predetermined by whom ?

Comment: Not all parts of my life are predetermined. If that were the case I am no different from an insentient computer program. Next, none else can determine my life. If that were the case, again, I'd be like a non-independent robot. Third, I cannot determine everything in my life. If that were the case, I would be God.

Comment: so, you are the cause for your own destiny, but not all parts of your life are predetermined because you are free to determine them, and you cannot escape the destiny that you yourself created without extraordinary effort, and you are not the sole cause for your destiny, because God enforces the reactions to your actions.

Comment: My understanding was wrong. The whole thing makes sense now :) maybe you should add an answer someday conveniently.

Comment: Glad I could help. This question is quite common in Hinduism, and has already been answered [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/conflicting-idea-about-karma-in-bhagavad-gita/29446#29446) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/is-our-destiny-predetermined-if-yes-then-why-do-our-actions-affect-our-karma)

Comment: Another thing. Some say and I have read somewhere, (don't know it's correct or incorrect) if I chat certain mantra then it's good for fortune. So, is that chanting a "good karma" and I have good results? @ram

Comment: correct. Mantras, Yagnas etc. are good actions. While killing, lying etc. are bad actions. Good actions give you good reactions, Bad actions give you bad reactions. The whole of scriptures is about how to determine your own destiny by doing good and avoiding bad. But mantras are like walking on knife-edge, or coding a computer program - one small bug and it has disastrous effects. Easier way is to do charity (to the right causes, namely Vedic pundits). The more charitable you are, the more money that comes your way (seems counter-intuitive, but it is what it is)